# Ubuntu won't boot after power failure - can't connect to lvmetad

Tags: boot

> WARNING : Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning. 
>   /dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root: clean. 494715/30187520 files, 4799821/120728576 blocks. 
>   You are in emergency mode...

I'm a new Linux user, and don't know what went wrong and how to fix this. 
(Yes, I know :ups ; it's on order) 
Xubuntu 17.10 installed on M. 2 NVMe with LVM; storage on RAID 1 array with LVM.

OK, learning "on the job" here. Went and did `journalctl -xb` and scrolled all the way down.

```
server04 kernel: JBD2: Invalid checksum recovering block 689 in log
server04 kernel: JBD2: Recovery failed
server04 kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-2): error loading journal
server04 systemd[1]: mnt-local-media: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
server04 systemd[1]: Failed to mount /mnt/local/media
...
server04 systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 1144 (plymouthd)
```

I tried `fsck /dev/md0`, got `/dev/md0 is in use`.
Tried `umount /dev/md0`, got `/dev/md0 is not mounted`.

I edited `/etc/fstab` to #-out what seems to be the relevant devices:
        # /dev/md0      /media  ext4    defaults        0       0
        # /dev/media/media      /mnt/local/media        ext4    defaults        0       0
This lets me boot up the system, but now what?

Comment: Is there any thing that should be attached to the system as per this error `Failed to mount /mnt/local/media` at boot time?

Comment: @George: the way I read it there is a checksum error in a log that pertains to /mnt/local/media, which is my raid array.
I guess to bypass the error, I should change a config file to have it not mount at boot.
And then I need to somehow fix the checksum error? How?

Comment: My problem seems similar to [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/440745/ext4-error-loading-journal)

How can I "reset the journal"?

Comment: try `journalctl --flush`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out to `sudo fsck /dev/media/media` on the now unmounted logical volume, which found a few errors which i let it fix. After this I changed `/etc/fstab` back to it original and problem was solved.

Comment: `sudo fsck /dev/<MY-DEV>` did it for me (without unmount).